# DetalView Yii2: how to output text with html tags

Tags: php, yii2

I use DetalView widget and I need <ВR> tag:

```
<?= DetailView::widget([
        'model' => $model,
        'attributes' => [
            'information:ntext',                
            [
                'attribute' => 'text',
                'value' => $model->getUserAttributes('getScientificWorks', 'text'),
            ],
         ],
    ])
    ?>
```

getUserAttributes returns string:

```
$string .= $item[$field] . ", ";
```

If instead of comma input <ВR>, then text will be like this: "text.. <ВR> ..text"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
...........

    [
        'attribute' => 'text',
        'value' => $model->getUserAttributes('getScientificWorks', 'text'),
        'format' => 'raw',
    ],

............
```

The "raw" format tells Yii2 not to do anything with the output. So it will display any html tag.

Answer (score 1):

You need to try to use `format` property like as  `'formate' => 'text'`.

```
  ........
        [
            'attribute' => 'text',
            'value' => $model->getUserAttributes('getScientificWorks', 'text'),
            'format' => 'text',
        ],
  .........
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$string .= nl2br($item[$field])`.